# localStorage issue - Items not displayed (JSON/JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, local-storage

I'm trying to get and sort all the items in localStorage and output it to an HTML page.

This is what I'm doing:

```
  <script>

    function ShoppingCart() {

        var totalPrice = 0;
        var output;
        var productName;
        var productAlbum;
        var productQuantity;
        var productPrice;
        var productSubTotal = 0;
        var totalPrice;

        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length-1; i++){

            var keyName = localStorage.key(i);
            if(keyName.indexOf('Product_')==0) // check if key startwith 'Product_'
            {
                var product =  localStorage.getItem('Product_'+i);

                var result = JSON.parse(product);

                var productName;
                var productAlbum;
                var productQuantity;
                var productPrice;
                var productSubTotal = 0;
                var totalPrice;

                productName = result.name
                productAlbum = result.album;
                productQuantity = result.quantity;
                productPrice = parseFloat(result.price).toFixed(2);
                productSubTotal = parseFloat(productQuantity * productPrice).toFixed(2);



                outputName = "<div id='cart-table'><table><tr><td><b>NAME: </b>" + productName + "</td></tr></div>" ;
                outputAlbum = "<tr><td><b>ALBUM: </b>" + productAlbum + "</td></tr>" ;
                outputQuantity = "<tr><td><b>QUANTITY: </b>" + productQuantity + "</td></tr>";
                outputPrice = "<tr><td><b>PRICE: </b> EUR " + productPrice + "</td></tr>";
                outputSubTotal = "<tr><td><b>SUB-TOTAL: </b> EUR " + productSubTotal + "</td></tr></table><br><br>";


                var outputTotal = "<table><tr><td><b>TOTAL:</b> EUR " + totalPrice + "</td></tr></table>";
                var TotalOutput = outputName + outputAlbum + outputQuantity + outputPrice + outputSubTotal + outputTotal;
                document.getElementById("Cart-Contents").innerHTML=TotalOutput;


            }
            }

            alert(TotalOutput);




    }

    window.onload = ShoppingCart;


</script>
```

The only item that is being output is the item named 'Proudct_0' in localStorage. Others are not being displayed!

This is what I have in localStorage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch2Ug.png

Any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something wrong in your code.
What do you think if Product_0 not in the localStorage?

```
var product =  localStorage.getItem('Product_'+i);
var result = JSON.parse(product);
```

may be null and throw an error.

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length-1; i++){
     var keyName = localStorage.key(i);
     if(keyName.indexOf('Product_')==0) // check if key startwith 'Product_'
     {
        var product = localStorage.getItem(keyName);
        //do your code here
     }
}
```

## Update

```
document.getElementById("Cart-Contents").innerHTML=TotalOutput;
```

it's replace, not append

Hope this help!

Comment: Nope, only one item is being displayed ! See the question with updated code.

Comment: `document.getElementById("Cart-Contents").innerHTML=TotalOutput; `
change to:
`document.getElementById("Cart-Contents").innerHTML= document.getElementById("Cart-Contents").innerHTML + TotalOutput;
`

Comment: Oops sorry! The same item is being displayed for multiple times!

Comment: Ahh fixed it. Had an extra for loop. Thanks!